# insert postgresql failed

Tags: c++, regex, postgresql

I can send data when I declare regex line to be commented out.But otherwise the data is sent empty.How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[I can send data when I declare regex line to be commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRjxO.png)

[When the regex line is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/589ld.png)

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. Please see the guidelines for how to ask a question that will help us understand what is the problem, what you did , and what is the desired result after successful execution.

Comment: Also, try to avoid relying on screenshots. They aren't google-able so others can't use them to find your question and learn from it and its answers. But yeah, this question is particularly opaque.

Comment: Please show the SQL statements. I don't think the screen captures are that useful.

Comment: connection C();
    work w(C);
    w.exec("INSERT INTO paket (id,paket_name,kaynak_ip,hedef_ip,kaynak_mac,hedef_mac,kaynak_port,hedef_port,data)"
                   "VALUES ("+
           w.quote(i)+","+
           w.quote("tcp")+","+
           w.quote(kaynak_ip)+","+
           w.quote(hedef_ip)+","+
           w.quote(kaynak_mac)+","+
           w.quote(hedef_mac)+","+
           w.quote(kaynak_port)+","+
           w.quote(hedef_port)+","+
           w.quote(data.c_str())+
           ")");
    w.commit();